# initMap() not a function when trying to plot multiple Google Map markers/info windows with data passed to the client via EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps-api-3, ejs

I am trying to plot out multiple map markers and info windows with Google Maps. I am not able to get the map to render when I add multiple markers, but I can get it to render with a central location. I am passing data from an API request in the backend to the client with EJS.

To start off, I can get the map to load at a central location given the users lat/lng that is generated from their zipcode in the backend. Here is what that code looks like on the client side `(search.ejs)` file:

```
<script>
    var map;

    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: { lat: <%= userLat %>, lng: <%= userLng %> },
            zoom: 10
        });
    }
</script>
```

After the post request completes and renders the `search.ejs` file, this block of code will render a Google Map with a central point to those coordinates. The coordinates are passed in from the backend via EJS. So I know that I can successfully use the data passed in via EJS to do stuff with Google Maps.

---

Now, I want to be able to render markers and info windows based on the returned API location data in the backend. I can pass the location coordinates from the backend API request to the client side with no problem. I know I am successfully passing the API location data to the client by way of a `console.log()` in the terminal and actually rendering the data to the HTML page with this EJS tag `<%= %>`.

Here is the code I have writted in my `search.ejs` template to render the Google Map with the markers and info windows:

```
 <script>
        var map;
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: { lat: <%= userLat %>, lng: <%= userLng %> },
                zoom: 10
            });
        }

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        var venueLocations = <%= venues.venues %>;

        for (i = 0; i < venueLocations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.mapsLatLng(venueLocations[i].location.lat, venueLocations[i].location.lng),
                map: map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(venueLocations[i].location);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }
    </script>
```

This is my `footer.ejs` file so you can see where I am loading the Google Maps API script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/public/js/frontend.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD_tYpqkFMkUc1mq2pzsBGySr6IeQkFhBA&callback=initMap" async defer>
</script>
```

And finally, this is the error that I am getting in the console when the map is trying to render with the markers:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (index):36

Uncaught Lb {message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Lb (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…MkUc1mq2pzsBGySr6IeQkFhBA&callback=initMap:150:59"}
```

The `Unexpected identifier (index):36` throws me off because I can only think that it is referring to `index.ejs`, but there is nothing at line 36 that has to do with this, so I am thinking I am wrong about what this means.

Comment: What does this rendered code look like if you view your page source in the browser: `center: { lat: <%= userLat %>, lng: <%= userLng %> },`

Comment: That is the latitude and longitude of a users imputed zip code passed in from the backend using EJS. So userLng and userLat are used to give the Google maps script center location coordinates.  To visualize: var userLng = -28.555; var userLat = 28.999; So these two values are what actually render to the client.

Comment: It'd definitely help to be able to see the full rendered HTML + JS

Comment: The entire index page is just a single DIV and then this map script that renders a map into that div. There is no external Js file handling the map script. I have to load the script inline on the page so I can use the EJS tags to pass data into the script from the backend. I can share the backend server code but that is handling my data and passing it to the client as expected. My issue occurs on the client side when this google maps script tries to render.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably because you've got a typo here causing an error:

```
position: new google.mapsLatLng(venueLocations[i].location.lat, venueLocations[i].location.lng),
```

This should be:

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(venueLocations[i].location.lat, venueLocations[i].location.lng),
```

Comment: My god.. I'll have to anxiously wait until this evening to see if this is it. I've been stuck on this since last night.

Comment: Still getting the same error, although this typo was definitely an issue.